# Capturing webcam snapshot with python silently

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, webcam

How is it possible to capture a snapshot of webcam or stream webcam in python without popping up windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using opencv-python package, the following piece of code momentarily captures the webcam information and saves the image in the directory specified. Note: The webcam indicator does light up for a fraction of second. I am not sure how that can be avoided as of now.

```
import cv2
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1) # Number which capture webcam in my machine
# try either VideoCapture(0) or (1) based on your camera availability
# in my desktop it works with (1)
check, frame = webcam.read()
cv2.imwrite(filename=r'<Your Directory>\saved_img.jpg', img=frame)
webcam.release()
```

This piece of code can be written in a bat file and you can trigger this for what ever event you are looking for (like startup security)

Comment: What about saving it in python code to be transferred over the network? This code seems to not be working on windows 10 x64. What version of python are you using? Ironically I was actually coding this for startup security, to send the captured image to my vps, so far I haven't found a method that's working.

Comment: I am on a windows 10 machine 64 bit processor, what error message are you getting? I use python 3.7 open cv 4.1.1

Comment: "saved_img.jpg, it looks like we don't support this file format" After opening the image. Not receiving any errors from the python interpreter. Seems to be saving the image in the wrong format.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6, 3.8, 2.7 tried on all to no avail. Maybe I should install 37?

Comment: Python version shouldn't be an issue, jpg is a conventional image format, png format would work too

Comment: The image size is 0 bytes, seems it didn't take the snapshot. In settings my windows machine allows apps to access webcam.

Comment: ok I discovered the issue changing webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1) to webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) took the snapshot if you can edit your answer to be a little more specific on this line of code i will accept it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: Glad that you were able to resolve it. I have a web cam and a laptop camera, so I was trying to capture from webcam so the number was set to 1 and not zero